# Passing values from pages to components in magnolia

Tags: java, magnolia

If I have a variable that I assign in my page:

```
<#assign myVar = "testing">

<@cms.area name="area-name"/>
```

And I'd like to be able to use that variable in a nested area or component, how do I pass it around the application?

```
<#list components as component>
    ${myVar}
</#list>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[@cms.area name="main" contextAttributes={"myVar":myVar}/]

${ctx.myVar}

Enjoy! :)